# Database driver error while starting corda nodes

Tags: corda

I have a bootstrapped corda network  locally and distributed these artifacts to the respective VMs. While I start one of the node I am getting the below error: I am using azure sql as the backend and jars are compiled using corda enterprise 4.3 and the database driver used is jdbc 6.4.

IntelliJ project target is set to Java jdk 1.8 only.

[INFO ] 2020-05-21T06:57:25,735Z [main] BasicInfo. - Database connection url is
: jdbc:sqlserver://<,servername>;databaseName=;;sendStringParametersAsUnicode=false {}
[INFO ] 2020-05-21T06:57:25,767Z [main] hikari.HikariDataSource. - HikariPool-1 - Starting... {}
[ERROR] 2020-05-21T06:57:25,814Z [main]
 internal.GeneralExceptionHandler. - Exception in thread "main" [errorCode=15ect6k, moreInformationAt=https://errors.corda.net/ENT/4.3/15ect6k] {}
java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/microsoft/sqlserver/jdbc/SQLServerDataSource has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 53.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_212]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763) ~[?:1.8.0_212]
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142) ~[?:1.8.0_212]
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:468) ~[?:1.8.0_212]
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:74) ~[?:1.8.0_212]
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:369) ~[?:1.8.0_212]
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:363) ~[?:1.8.0_212]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_212]
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:362) ~[?:1.8.0_212]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424) ~[?:1.8.0_212]
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349) ~[?:1.8.0_212]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357) ~[?:1.8.0_212]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.UtilityElf.createInstance(UtilityElf.java:100) ~[HikariCP-3.3.1.jar:?]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.initializeDataSource(PoolBase.java:316) ~[HikariCP-3.3.1.jar:?]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.(PoolBase.java:109) ~[HikariCP-3.3.1.jar:?]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.(HikariPool.java:108) ~[HikariCP-3.3.1.jar:?]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.(HikariDataSource.java:81) ~[HikariCP-3.3.1.jar:?]
    at net.corda.node.internal.DataSourceFactory.createDataSource(DataSourceFactory.kt:42) ~[corda-node-4.3.jar:?]
    at net.corda.node.internal.DataSourceFactory.createDataSource$default(DataSourceFactory.kt:39) ~[corda-node-4.3.jar:?]
    at net.corda.node.internal.AbstractNodeKt.startHikariPool(AbstractNode.kt:1364) ~[corda-node-4.3.jar:?]
    at net.corda.node.internal.AbstractNode.startDatabase(AbstractNode.kt:1004) ~[corda-node-4.3.jar:?]
    at net.corda.node.internal.Node.startDatabase(Node.kt:537) ~[corda-node-4.3.jar:?]
    at net.corda.node.internal.AbstractNode.start(AbstractNode.kt:445) ~[corda-node-4.3.jar:?]
    at net.corda.node.internal.Node.start(Node.kt:552) ~[corda-node-4.3.jar:?]
    at net.corda.node.internal.EnterpriseNode.start(EnterpriseNode.kt:210) ~[corda-node-4.3.jar:?]
    at net.corda.node.internal.NodeStartup.startNode(NodeStartup.kt:211) ~[corda-node-4.3.jar:?]
    at net.corda.node.internal.NodeStartupCli$runProgram$2.run(NodeStartup.kt:132) ~[corda-node-4.3.jar:?]
    at net.corda.node.internal.NodeStartup$initialiseAndRun$5.invoke(NodeStartup.kt:188) ~[corda-node-4.3.jar:?]
    at net.corda.node.internal.NodeStartup$initialiseAndRun$5.invoke(NodeStartup.kt:139) ~[corda-node-4.3.jar:?]
    at net.corda.node.internal.NodeStartupLogging$DefaultImpls.attempt(NodeStartup.kt:538) ~[corda-node-4.3.jar:?]
    at net.corda.node.internal.NodeStartup.attempt(NodeStartup.kt:139) ~[corda-node-4.3.jar:?]
    at net.corda.node.internal.NodeStartup.initialiseAndRun(NodeStartup.kt:187) ~[corda-node-4.3.jar:?]
    at net.corda.node.internal.NodeStartupCli.runProgram(NodeStartup.kt:130) ~[corda-node-4.3.jar:?]
    at net.corda.cliutils.CordaCliWrapper.call(CordaCliWrapper.kt:190) ~[corda-tools-cliutils-4.3.jar:?]
    at net.corda.node.internal.NodeStartupCli.call(NodeStartup.kt:85) ~[corda-node-4.3.jar:?]
    at net.corda.node.internal.NodeStartupCli.call(NodeStartup.kt:66) ~[corda-node-4.3.jar:?]
    at picocli.CommandLine.execute(CommandLine.java:1173) ~[picocli-3.9.6.jar:3.9.6]
    at picocli.CommandLine.access$800(CommandLine.java:141) ~[picocli-3.9.6.jar:3.9.6]
    at picocli.CommandLine$RunLast.handle(CommandLine.java:1367) ~[picocli-3.9.6.jar:3.9.6]
    at picocli.CommandLine$RunLast.handle(CommandLine.java:1335) ~[picocli-3.9.6.jar:3.9.6]
    at picocli.CommandLine$AbstractParseResultHandler.handleParseResult(CommandLine.java:1243) ~[picocli-3.9.6.jar:3.9.6]
    at picocli.CommandLine.parseWithHandlers(CommandLine.java:1526) ~[picocli-3.9.6.jar:3.9.6]
    at net.corda.cliutils.CordaCliWrapperKt.start(CordaCliWrapper.kt:73) ~[corda-tools-cliutils-4.3.jar:?]
    at net.corda.node.Corda.main(Corda.kt:13) ~[corda-node-4.3.jar:?]

Answer (score 0):

Can you double-check you're using the jre8 version of the SQL Server JDBC driver.

Comment: In intellij project I checked its using jdk 1.8

Comment: Yes, but the error is saying that the SQL Server JDBC driver you are using is compiled with Java 9, which won't be recognized by your current Java Runtime (8). So you need to use the Java 8 version of the driver: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.microsoft.sqlserver/mssql-jdbc/6.4.0.jre8